# Use linq to search a string[]

Tags: c#, linq, arrays

Im new to linq and trying to learn some basic? functionality. I have a string that im splitting into a string array and I want to query the array for values. My code.

```
string input = "a1,b2,c3,d4";

var collection = input.Split(',');

string output = collection.OfType<string>().Where(r => (string)r.Contains("a").FirstOrDefaule();
```

I think im on the right track but Its not quite there. I want the output to be a1.

The error is cannot convert bool to string, which makes sense, but how would you do this without using the contains method?

Comment: Does: `string output= urls.OfType<string>().Where(r => r.Contains("a")).FirstOrDefault();` work for you? Just `Where` on its own returns another enumerable, not a single string. You need to use methods like `First, FirstOrDefault, Single, SingleOrDefault` (or others) to get a single entry. EDIT: And could you post the _actual_ code you're using? The code you posted won't compile (missing a parenthesis), and what are `urls`?

Comment: Sorry I am using in line code that gets items dynamically and doesnt make sense to post. I will edit original code to reflect properly.

Comment: Also, what's the point of `collection.OfType<string>`? That won't perform conversion of a non-string (like a `Uri`) to a string. Does `collection` have a set of mixed types (that is, is it something like `List<object>`)? If `collection` is already a `string[]` (or rather, `IEnumerable<string>`) then you can just start calling LINQ directly on it.

Comment: Right, thats what andrews answer does, I think. I did not know that was possible. Separate question I guess, but if this was a collection of object[], would the code you provided work? Ive been studying LINQ lately and just now beginning to really apply it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code should work:

```
string output = collection.First(r => r.Contains("a"));
```

`Contains` is probably the most efficient way.

`Where` gives you a new list of all elements which have an "a"; `First` (or `FirstOrDefault`) will return a single value.

Comment: this worked best. Its not what I was asking but its a way better way to do it. Thank you. As i said im new with linq and i didnt even know this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use cast to string in Where clause? You don't need it. 
Try this

```
string output= urls.OfType<string>().Where(r => r.Contains("a")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It was contains in original message. And I try to fix it. But looks like it is not need. You can use more short version of code  string output = collection.FirstOrDefault(item=>item.Contains("a"));

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
string output= collection.Where(r => r.Contains("a")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You could improve the quality of your answer by explaining what you did and why.

Comment: It is so simple i use linq to collection , the clause  where is to filter and FirstOrDefault is to select the result.